# compilation of same c program from different directory generates object code of different size

Tags: c, makefile, compilation, size

I have a c program kept at different directories 'source1/abc.c' and 'source2/abc.c'. I want to generate the object code in 'object1/abc.o' and 'object2/abc.o'. Both abc.c program in source1 and source2 directory are same. But after compilation both the objects( i.e. abc.o ) of object1 and object2 are of different size. I am taking same flag for compilation.

I tries compiling the code from some other directory, other than object1 and object2 and the size after compilation are same.

```
cc -c source1/abc.c -DLINUX -D_LARGE_THREADS -D_THREAD_SAFE -D_REENTRANT -pthread -D_GNU_SOURCE -g -fPIC -O3  -lpthread  -lm  -lrt  -o object1/abc.o
cc -c source2/abc.c -DLINUX -D_LARGE_THREADS -D_THREAD_SAFE -D_REENTRANT -pthread -D_GNU_SOURCE -g -fPIC -O3  -lpthread  -lm  -lrt  -o object2/abc.o
```

The size of abc.o should be equal or does it depend on the directories from which it is running?
What are the dependencies while compilation of c program?

Comment: Are the files that get included the same?  You can just preprocess the code using `-E` and compare the output.  You'll want to change the `-o ...` option, too.

Comment: OT:  What is `_LARGE_THREADS`?  I can't find any reference to that, so it appeas to be something created for your code.  That's [a reserved identifier per **7.1.3 Reserved identifiers**](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3):  "All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're compiling with -g option, which adds debug Information to the object file. These might contain path Information of the source files, so different paths lead to different symbols and a different total file size.

Comment: Yes it was because of -g flag. I removed the -g flag. And the size is same now.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of the -g.

Comment: Yes it was because of -g flag. I removed the -g flag. And the size is same now.